# Is it possible to insert text boxes/labels into a chart using vba?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

I'm currently writing a program that will graph an x-ray spectrum, and then calculate where all of the peaks are, and what they should be labeled. However, I'm not sure how I can add the labels of each peak using excel vba. I know the x and y coordinate of the tip of the peak on the chart (based on the axes units). Is there any way to use that information to place a label slightly above, or slightly to the right of that point?

Below, I've included an example of what I'm going for.

The peaks will be different elements based on what data is input. The tips of the peaks will also be in different x and y positions. So I think it would be best if there was some way to add the label based on x and y coordinates of the tips of the peaks, since I always know those values.

Looking around on the internet, I can't find any real information on how to do this, if it's even possible. I'm hoping you guys can help me out!

[image: An X-Ray Spectrum]

Comment: Definitely do-able. You can add shapes (like textboxes) to the ChartArea object.  However, in this case it seems like it would be easier to just hijack the points' `DataLabel` object and manipulate the text therein.  Selectively delete the `DataLabel` (or set a null-string text) on those points which you do not want to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely do-able. You can add shapes (like textboxes) to the ChartArea object.  However, in this case it seems like it would be easier to just hijack the points' `DataLabel` object and manipulate the text therein.

```
Dim pt As Point
Dim p As Long
Dim dl As DataLabel
Dim srs As Series
Dim cht As Chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(1)
srs.HasDataLabels = False '## Turn off the data labels
For Each pt In srs.Points
    p = p + 1
    If [logic or function to determine your peaks] Then  
        pt.HasDataLabel = True
        Set dl = pt.DataLabel
        dl.Text = "whatever you want it to be"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: For a chart like this with a large number of points it might be faster to turn on labels one-by-one.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa196429(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @TimWilliams bingo. modified my answer in light of that.

Comment: Thank you! This is already amazing. How would this code change if I already knew my peak value? Like if I had a variable named peakvalue before going into a labeling loop? Is there a way to find the point that equals that specific value, and only label that one?

Comment: I think you would still need to loop unless you know the point's index position (which is what we can obtain by looping, with the iterator variable `p` in the answer). The `If` statement could be like `If srs.Values(p) = peakValue Then...`

Comment: Is there a way that I can change this code to allow me to run it multiple times to label multiple peaks?

Right now, if I run it a second time on another peak, it wipes the label from the previous peak. Probably due to the `srs.HasDataLabels = False` line. I have multiple graphs in multiple sheets, so I can't use a global variable to ensure that line only happens for the first time the code is ran though, since it'll be used in the same program and same workbook on a graph in another sheet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem like that line is necessary.

Comment: Yes, there's certainly a way to do that but I'm not in a position to assist with that at the moment. You can most likely figure it out with a little trial & error :)